# Constructing a plot from a subset of data with time as the variable, receiving a numerical expression error

Tags: r, time, plot, subset

I am fairly new to R, so sorry if this is a relatively simple question. I am trying to take data in a csv format and trying to plot a variable (listed below as PMAJ.ug.per.m3) vs. a subset of time (listed below as PM.Time). I have provided a sample of the data below.

```
   X    Site    PM.Time PMAJ.ug.per.m3
1   Run8     09:34:09   168  
2   Run8     09:34:19   32  
3   Run8     09:34:29   34  
4   Run8     09:34:39   26  
5   Run8     09:34:49   24  
6   Run8     09:34:59   30  
7   Run8     09:35:09   23  
8   Run8     09:35:19   17  
9   Run8     09:35:29   21  
10  Run8     09:35:39   20  
11  Run8     09:35:49   37  
12  Run8     09:35:59   26  
13  Run8     09:36:09   16  
14  Run8     09:36:19   21  
15  Run8     09:36:29   69
```

My code is the following and is generating errors that are listed below:

```
with(subset(aim1dat,PM.Time< 09:35:59 & PM.Time> 09:34:19), plot(PM.Time,PMAJ.ug.per.m3))

Error in axis(1, at = (xat[1L:nx] + xat[2L:(nx + 1L)] - off)/2, labels = xaxlabels,  : 
  no locations are finite
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In 9:35:59 : numerical expression has 27 elements: only the first used
2: In Ops.factor(PM.Time, 9:35:59) : < not meaningful for factors
3: In 9:34:19 : numerical expression has 26 elements: only the first used
4: In Ops.factor(PM.Time, 9:34:19) : > not meaningful for factors
```

The time is formatted for the rest of the data in 24 hour format (i.e. 09:00:00 to 15:00:00). I am not sure how to correct this issue. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should coerce your factors to a valid date/time format. For example , here I convert all dates to a `POSIXct`:

```
aim1dat$PM.Time <- as.POSIXct(aim1dat$PM.Time, format='%H:%M:%S')

dat <- subset(aim1dat,PM.Time<  as.POSIXct("09:35:59", format='%H:%M:%S') & 
               PM.Time>  as.POSIXct("09:34:19", format='%H:%M:%S'))
with(dat,plot(PM.Time,PMAJ.ug.per.m3,type='l'))
```

[image]

Comment: If it's a factor, don't you think he will need `as.character`?

Comment: How do you make the time actually show the format H:HMM:SS. For example 09:34:50? Your code just has it in a MM:SS format.